# From an ActiveX control, can I tell what domain it is being created from?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, activex, atl

If possible, I want to prevent my ActiveX control from being accidentally executed by untrusted pages, because it can be used to download and run a file.

One idea is to have the control know the domain of the HTML page it is instantiated on, and prompt the user if they trust this domain. It would remember this choice in the registry. If the control was used by a page rendered from a different domain, the user would be asked to trust the new domain.

Is there a way for an ActiveX control to query IE and ask what domain the page was downloaded from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, implement [IObjectWithSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768220(VS.85).aspx) and cache the pointer you're given in `SetSite()`.

Then:

1. `QueryInterface()` your site for `IID_IServiceProvider`.
2. `QueryService()` the `IServiceProvider` for `SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_IServiceProvider`.
3. `QueryService()` the top level `IServiceProvider` for `SID_SWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2`.
4. Call [get_LocationURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752130(v=VS.85).aspx).